how commit as second git account when I have verify git on my device
I want to push my codes to my work-git-hub account but after login with the android studio to my git-hub account, git tries to push with personal account git that verifies with GitHub (gpg) and it doesn't have permission to push codes.
I want a solution for pushing my codes with the right git account (work git account).
my personal git account is verified

https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%5Bgithub%5D+multiple+accounts
